# How to generate UUID in DB2 SQL

Tags: db2, uuid

I have a table where I want to add a UUID column and insert UUID's for the existing rows. But I am unable to find a way to get this done. Appreciate your inputs on this.

Comment: Do you want to generate UUIDs and insert them into a new column? What is the exact problem or error you ran into?

Comment: I don't find an inbuilt function to generate UUID in DB2 SQL

Answer (score 1):

Db2 doesn't have UUID columns. Use generated as identity column instead.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_GENERATED (I INT) IN USERSPACE1;
INSERT INTO TEST_GENERATED (I) VALUES 0, 0, 0;
SET INTEGRITY FOR TEST_GENERATED OFF;
ALTER TABLE TEST_GENERATED ADD ID INT NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE TEST_GENERATED ALTER ID DROP DEFAULT SET GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY;
SET INTEGRITY FOR TEST_GENERATED GENERATE IDENTITY IMMEDIATE CHECKED NOT INCREMENTAL;
INSERT INTO TEST_GENERATED (I) VALUES 1, 1, 1;
SELECT * FROM TEST_GENERATED;

|I          |ID         |
|-----------|-----------|
|0          |1          |
|0          |2          |
|0          |3          |
|1          |4          |
|1          |5          |
|1          |6          |
```